# Serialilzer doesn't accept value. Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two one to one models User and UserData. In UserSerializer I have this field:

```
info = serrializers.CharField(source='user_data.info')
```

But if I pass data to "info" through UserViewSet API using PATCH method, serializer contains None in "info" field and data can't be saved.

Comment: can you show the serializer full definition and the data that you are passing.

Comment: "serializer contains None in "info" field" << could you explain where / how / why you say that ? serializers don't "contains" values directly. there's only one way to get the value though it's not always well understood.